# Login redirection with WPML

Tags: wordpress

This code only works for the default language, since ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE returns

only the default language code in login_rediraction.

How can I get a second language?

```
function my_login_redirect( $url, $request, $user ){
    $langs =  ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE;
    if( $user && is_object( $user ) && is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) ) {
        if( $user->has_cap( 'marketing')) {
            if($langs == 'en'){
                $url = home_url('/en-slug/');
            }else{
                $url = home_url('/fr/fr-slug/');
            }
        }
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Check https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_locale/

Comment: it works that way too

Comment: "How can I get a second language?" Is not clear - explain little more

Comment: The site has 2 languages (EN and FR), icl_language_code in login_redirect returns only the default language (EN) from both the English page and from French